# Managing node child processes generated with spawn

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, phantomjs, fork, spawn

I have built a service that takes a screenshot of a URL. I have built this using a Node and Phantom JS.

My Node app works as follows:

1. A simple app that receives an API requests to indicate which URL to load and take a screenshot of
2. The app spawns a child Phantom process which takes the screenshot and saves it to a temp file on the server
3. The main process uploads the image to S3
4. The main process fires an API request back to the initial website to say the image is uploaded with the image’s URL
5. The temporary file is deleted

**A diagram of how it works:**
[image]

This works fine for a single request, no problem. However, when I throw multiple, consecutive requests at this service I get strange results. Each request received by the service spawns a Phantom JS process and a screenshot is taken, but the data in the API request sent back to the main website is often not correct. Regularly the system will send back the image URL from a screenshot created by another child process.

My hunch is that when the spawned process exits, it sends the API request to the original website with whatever data it has then just received, rather than the data for the process it’s just completed.

I feel like this should be any easy thing to manage, but I haven’t quite found the right approach. Does anyone have any tips/tricks for managing the child processes created with `spawn`, especially when they exit. I would like to perform another task based on this exited process.

My initial thought was to keep an array of the child process PID’s along with the related data I had and do a lookup in this array when the child process exits. This didn’t seem to fix the problem though - I still had incorrect data being sent back to the main website. I do wonder if I implemented this correctly though. I defined the array on each API request received by the service, so thinking about it, it would have been recreated on each request…I think.

Another thought was that I should be using `fork` instead of `spawn`. I think this would allow me to communicate with the child process, but as far as I can see I can only use this to run a JS file, not a executable like Phantom. Is this correct?

I feel a bit like I’m reinventing the wheel at this point but any tips would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why `spawn` shouldn't be fine.  Intuition suggests that you are mishandling something because of an assumption involving callbacks and closures... You shouldn't have to keep an array of the spawned processes, if each process's callbacks have access to the right data structures.  Can you show some code?  Specifically, can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `Each request received by the service spawns a Phantom JS process ` that is somewhat ineffective, the better practive here is to creat a pool of longer-living PhantomJS processes that receive requests for work. See here: https://www.codementor.io/schumachertony90/scaling-phantomjs-taking-thousands-of-full-page-screenshots-every-day-csvl1j6ur

Comment: Both `spawn` and `fork` return a `ChildProcess` instance. You can manage piping yourself and handle messaging between child processes and main process. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback.